# Team Rocket Balloons in Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

Quite simply; how often do the Team Rocket Balloons spawn, and what, if any, is the limit to how many can spawn per day?

Comment: You might have encountered much more balloons yesterday, because there was a Team Rocket take-over

Answer (score 1):

Team Rocket balloons spawn every 6 hours. Specifically, one will spawn the first time you open the game after midnight, 6am, noon, and 6pm.

For the duration of the 4th Anniversary Go Fest Battle Challenge this was increased to every 3 hours, and for a short period on Sunday July 12th 2020 they were every 20 minutes.